# Scale of knowledge and fact base for an expert system

Tags: artificial-intelligence, clips, expert-system, knowledge-management

I am new to development of expert systems.I have started programming with clips a few simple codes like animal identification,mini version of mycin etc.I want to increase the knowledge and fact base(to a million facts) for my programs so i was wondering if there was any Database management system to make this process easier.I would like to know how to implement this in general.

Comment: it's a quite broad question. can you narrow it down?

Comment: I basically want to know how do u add large knowledge and fact bases to CLIPS. The process of writing manually is tiring so it possible to integrate some other program ? Also can CLIPS manage such a huge knowledge base?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of the box, the only mechanism for editing and loading rules/facts is through text files. CLIPS can be integrated with other languages so it's possible to add alternate means for storing and editing your rules/facts, you'd just have to write the code to integrate the pieces.